# Parsing parentheses on search expression - Scala parser combinator

Tags: scala, parsing, lexer

I am writing a parser for a search expression. 
Ex.

```
a = "zyx" and ( b < 5 or c > 9)
```

I wrote this parser but it's not able to match the parentheses, getting this error:

```
failure: identifier expected
a = "zyx" and ( b < 5 or c > 9)
              ^
```

What can I do to be able to match the paretheses

```scala
class SearchQueryParser extends StandardTokenParsers {
  def expr: Parser[Expression] = orExp | "(" ~> orExp ~ ")"

  def orExp: Parser[Expression] = {
    andExp *("or" ^^^ {(a: Expression, b: Expression) => BoolExp("OR", (a, b))})
  }

  def andExp: Parser[Expression] = {
    compareExp *("and" ^^^ {(a: Expression, b: Expression) => BoolExp("AND", (a, b))})
  }

  def compareExp: Parser[Expression] = {
    identifier ~ rep(
      ("=" | "!=" | "<" | ">") ~ literal ^^ {
        case op ~ rhs => (op, rhs)
      }
    ) ^^ {
      case (acc, ("=", rhs: Expression)) => Binomial("=", acc, rhs)  
      case (acc, ("!=", rhs: Expression)) => Binomial("!=", acc, rhs)
      case (acc, ("<", rhs: Expression)) => Binomial("<", acc, rhs)
      case (acc, (">", rhs: Expression)) => Binomial(">", acc, rhs)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `compareExp` rule looks strange to me. It allows `x < 5  > 1`, but not `1 < x < 5`. I'm not sure whether that's what you intended or not.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I actually don't need any of the expression as only Binomials should be allowed. I change my grammar accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current grammar only allows parentheses in the `expr` rule, which I assume is your main rule, and the `expr` rule is never used by any other rule. So parentheses are only allowed around the entire expression.

What you want to do is to put `"(" ~ expr ~ ")"` in the lowest place where parenthesized expressions would be allowed. As I understand your grammar, that would probably meaning allowing it as an alternative to `compareExp` in `andExp` (assuming you don't want to allow parentheses inside `compareExp`s).

Answer (score 1):

As @sepp2k mentioned you need to put your parentheses on the lowest place where parentheses is allowed. In your case it should be in the compareExp:

```scala
  def compareExp: Parser[Expression] = {
    "(" ~> expr <~ ")" | identifier ~ rep(
      ("=" | "!=" | "<" | ">") ~ literal ^^ {
        case op ~ rhs => (op, rhs)
      }
    ) ^^ {
      case (acc, ("=", rhs: Expression)) => Binomial("=", acc, rhs)  
      case (acc, ("!=", rhs: Expression)) => Binomial("!=", acc, rhs)
      case (acc, ("<", rhs: Expression)) => Binomial("<", acc, rhs)
      case (acc, (">", rhs: Expression)) => Binomial(">", acc, rhs)
    }
  }
```

and `exp` method should not handle the parentheses

```scala
 def expr: Parser[Expression] = orExp
```